# Live monitoring of total thread stack size in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, memory, stack

As I know in Java thread stack size depends on JVM and OS Architecture and by default (unless -Xss is set) varies between 256k and 1m. Is there a way or tool allowing to see total stack size consumed by all currently running threads in runtime like I can see Heap Size or Metaspace Size using JVisualVM from JDK package? I understand that this value can be calculated as thread stack size * number of currently running threads however it would be great to monitor this value in runtime.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/apangin/jstackmem/blob/master/jstackmem.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the default stack size is platform specific, but that does not mean that the platform specific default "varies".  My recollection is that the defaults have not changed (for any given "architecture") for a long time.  (Probably since Java 5, if not earlier.  But don't quote me!)

You also can't use the default to accurately determine how much stack memory has actually been allocated, since:

1. The platform default can be overridden via the `-xss` command line option.  As you noted.
2. A non-default stack size can be specified when each `Thread` object is created.
3. The stack is only actually allocated when the `Thread` is started.  (And it is deallocated when the `Thread` terminates.)

So if you wanted to measure the actual allocated stack memory you would need to iterate all of the threads and find their actual stack sizes.  The first should be relatively straight forwards: traverse the `ThreadGroup` tree.  (I don't think you can guarantee that you will see all threads in a traversal, but that shouldn't matter.)  The second is more difficult since there is no getter for the private `Thread.stackSize` field ... and that field only records the parameter that the application supplied to the `Thread` constructor.

However, since typical applications just use the default stack size, counting the threads and multiplying by the default size will typically give a good estimate for the total thread stack usage.

It may also be possible to infer a JVM's allocated stack memory by examining the processes memory segments using the methodology of Andrei Pangin's [stackmem](https://github.com/apangin/jstackmem) script.  (Noting that this is Linux specific, and that it relies on the JVM requesting individual memory segments from the OS for thread stacks.)

On the other hand, if you wanted to know the amount of stack space currently *used* (not just allocated), that would be difficult to get from within the application.  And if you wanted to get it via an agent, I suspect that you would need to freeze the JVM first.  That wouldn't be acceptable for regular monitoring.

But the bottom line is that getting the information will be (at least!) non-trivial and (IMO) probably not worth the effort.  There is not a lot that you can do<sup>1</sup> with an accurate measure of allocated stack space that you can't already do by looking at thread counts and multiplying ...

> ... it would be great to monitor this value in runtime.

Not convinced :-)

---

<sup>1 - There are two possible reasons for wanting to know how much stack memory is used: you need to optimize or curiosity.  In the former case knowing how much stack memory is used doesn't tell you directly how much ought to be used.  To determine the latter, you actually need to determine whether you have too many threads, or if those threads' stacks need to be as big as they currently are.  Reducing stack memory usage "on principle" or because some says it is "best practice" could get you into trouble.</sup>

Comment: you had me at last two words! and agreed. but the all mighty Pangin [wrote a minor snippet for this](https://github.com/apangin/jstackmem/blob/master/jstackmem.py). Granted, it was for a presentation only.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [JProfiler](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html).
If you want to see it live in action before trying it yourself, check [this](https://www.ej-technologies.com/blog/2009/07/thread-states-in-the-cpu-profiling-views/)

Also, your idea that thread stack size varies between 256k and 1m is absolutely correct.

In JDK 8, HotSpot installation comes with a feature named Native Memory Tracking (default: disabled).  To enable it, use:

```
-XX:NativeMemoryTracking=[off|detail|summary]
```

After enabling NMT, you can examine the memory footprint taken by either Thread or Thread Stack using:

```
jcmd <pid> VM.native_memory [summary | detail | baseline | summary.diff | detail.diff | shutdown] [scale= KB | MB | GB]
```